# How is the value being assigned to the member of the class in the code below?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

In the code snippet how is 10 getting assigned to x ? There is no definition for copy constructor, so the default one is being used.

```
class X 
{
public:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    X a = {10};
    X b = a;
    cout << a.x << " " << b.x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: {10} is treated as an object of type `X` and `a` is initialized with it by using the default copy constructor

Comment: What do you mean "the default one"? The compiler will generate a "default" copy ctor, which will initialize `x`.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername `{10}` is *not* treated as an object of type `X`.

Comment: "*There is no definition for copy constructor, so the default one is being used.*" This would appear to be the answer to your question. So... why did you ask it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Clearly has misunderstood what such a copy constructor does.

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe I'm a bit rusty. So what happens with {10} in this line?

Answer (score 2):

Right, well yes the implicit copy constructor will be called, and since that constructor copies all the members, there's nothing magical here.

> `[C++14: 12.8/7]:` If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared *implicitly*. *[..]*
>
> `[C++14: 12.8/15]:` The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class `X` performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. *[..]*

An implicit copy constructor that didn't actually copy anything wouldn't be of much use now would it?

Comment: Thanks. I just started with the language and misunderstood the copy constructor. Thanks for the explanation.